# HPE SAS Expander card with breakout cables?

Tags: sas, hpe

I have an old HP ML350 G6 server and I was wondering if I could buy a SAS expander card (this one 468406-B21) and buy a couple of SFF-8087 breakout cables and use it for my internal SATA drives instead of connecting it to a back plane?

Or does the expander card only work with a back plane?

I just ordered a LSI SAS2008-8I cards but I'm thinking about canceling the order and buy this expander card instead. I have 6 WD Black SATA drives connected to the motherboard right now that I'm using with ZFS but it's really slow and I'm hoping a dedicated card will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Expander cards in general, and this expander card will work with standard SFF-8087 breakout cables (you can even attach a breakout cable to the SFF-8088 "tape" port and attach disks to it).

However, you still need to find a way to attach the expander card to your system, and you need either a SAS raid or a HBA controller to do so, so the expander card is not a replacement for the LSI SAS controller, it can only extend it to more drives.